# Proper formatting of Command Substitution

Tags: shell, applescript, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I am trying to add the currently playing song if there is one to my ZSH prompt. I'm using a JXA command `osascript -l JavaScript -e "Application('Music').currentTrack.name()"`. I am trying to assign it to a variable. and then echo that command.

```
precmd() {
  SONG=$( echo -e osascript -l JavaScript -e "Application('Music').currentTrack.name()" )
  LEFT=echo $SONG
  RIGHT="$(dracula_time_segment) $(battery_pct_prompt)"
  RIGHTWIDTH=$(($COLUMNS-${#LEFT}))
}
```

I've tried a number of variations eg: echo inside and outside the expression and various flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `echo` at all, as demonstrated by your later command substitutions when setting `RIGHT`; command substitution just takes a command and executes it.

```
SONG=$(osascript -l JavaScript -e "Application('Music').currentTrack.name()")
LEFT="$SONG"
```

You could combine the previous two commands; `SONG` isn't needed.

```
LEFT=$(osascript ...)
```

Comment: When I tried to use just the variable it evaluates the name of the song as a command that should be run. It's possible I am still doing something in correctly though. But I did also answer the question and it seems to work. Using your method also works for me if I add echo before the variable.

Comment: Because you weren't using command substitution for the original assignment to `LEFT` at all. `LEFT=echo $SONG` is not the same as `LEFT=$(echo $SONG)`.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation very much.